# What are the performance implications of running a Node.js app off of a network drive mounted via sshfs?

Tags: node.js, sshfs

Suppose I mount a remote location using sshfs. What would be the performance implications of running a Node.js app located on the mounted network drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues to think of, server startup and then runtime data and file access.

For server startup, node.js has to load all the modules that your code uses (modules are usually loaded during startup, not later during runtime).  So, if a drive is mounted remotely that disk access may be a bit slower and thus your server may take longer to start.  But, once it is started and all the modules it depends upon are loaded into memory, there's no longer any access to that drive for the running of your code.  node.js code is held in memory after it is loaded. 
 So, it's a one time handicap that might just make your server start a little slower.

If your app also accesses files stored on that server (such as HTML templates, static CSS or client JS files or databases), then each access to those files may be slower and that slower speed may manifest itself in a server that responds to requests (loading pages, processing database transactions, etc...) slower than it could.

Because of the asynchronous nature of file and network access in node.js, it probably won't change the scalability of the server as a whole, but it would likely affect the speed at which it can respond to certain types of requests.

Local caching could perhaps alleviate some of the performance impact of slower drive access.

You may also have a reliability issue.  If the remote link to the drive is not completely reliable then your server may have a reliability issue.  Usually, servers work from local drives for both reliability and speed reasons.

Comment: This is true. However I would warn that start up time might take longer than you expect, depending on the modules you use. Node.js applications generally has lots of modules (whether you depend on them directly, or directly through your dependencies). This means it may load hundreds or even thousands of files, if you're not careful.